# SetState Not Scroll able ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll

I meet problem with the ListView. When i scroll listview to top I will disable Scroll. But when I scroll down again, the listview not scroll down. I want when I scroll up it will able scroll down again. Pls help me !

```
class PageTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PageTwo> createState() => _PageTwoState();
}

class _PageTwoState extends State<PageTwo> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  ScrollPhysics scrollPhysics = const BouncingScrollPhysics();

  scrollControllerListener() {
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels <= 0) {
        setState(() {
          scrollPhysics = const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollControllerListener();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () {
        setState(() {
          scrollPhysics = const BouncingScrollPhysics();
        });
      },
      onVerticalDragDown: (details) {
        setState(() {
          scrollPhysics = const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
        });
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
        controller: scrollController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: scrollPhysics,
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return const NewWidget();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Tell me about how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

That's becuz when u reach the top, you u

> scrollPhysics = const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();

This makes your ListView won't be able to scroll anymore. I don't know why you want to disable scroll when u reach the top, it seems weird. But if you still want to do that way, I have small trick for you: Use `Future.delayed` with a few milisecs after assiged `scrollPhysics = const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();`. Like this:

```
scrollControllerListener() {
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels <= 0) {
        setState(() {
          scrollPhysics = NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
          Future.delayed(
            Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            () => scrollPhysics = BouncingScrollPhysics(), // YOU MAY NEED TO ADD A setState() HERE
          );
        });
      }
    });
```

A small advice relates to clean code: write a separated function for adding scroll controller's listener.

Comment: i don't want add Future.delayed, how can't i fixed it again without Future.delay ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use the `NotificationListener` widget to intercept scroll notifications and dynamically change the `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` to `BouncingScrollPhysics` and vice versa. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this behavior

```
class _PageTwoState extends State<PageTwo> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  ScrollPhysics scrollPhysics = BouncingScrollPhysics();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels <= 0) {
        setState(() {
          scrollPhysics = NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          scrollPhysics = BouncingScrollPhysics();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () {
        setState(() {
          scrollPhysics = BouncingScrollPhysics();
        });
      },
      onVerticalDragDown: (details) {
        setState(() {
          scrollPhysics = NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
        });
      },
      child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
          // Handle scroll events here if needed
          return false;
        },
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: scrollController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          physics: scrollPhysics,
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return const NewWidget();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The first time you scroll down after scroll up will not be able to scroll. How can i resolve it ?